# Unable to inject view using Butterknife 8.1.0

Tags: android, android-view, butterknife

I want to use Butterknife in my project . As described [Here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) I set up Butterknife like this.

**In Project level module :**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

**In Module Level**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.id.myprojectid"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile files('libs/libphonenumber-7.0.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'

}
```

**Inside Activity**

```
 @BindView(R.id.et_password) EditText et_password;
    @BindView(R.id.et_fullname)  EditText etFullname;
    @BindView(R.id.et_email) EditText etEmail;
    @BindView(R.id.et_contact) EditText et_contact;
    @BindView(R.id.et_refer)  EditText et_referId;
    @BindView(R.id.cbPasswordVisible) CheckBox checkBox;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
}
```

But when i run my application i get this following error message.

```
Error:(20, 32) error: method castView in enum Finder cannot be applied to given types;
required: View,int,String,Class<T>
found: View,int,String
reason: cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Object declared in method <T>castView(View,int,String,Class<T>)
Error:(22, 31) error: method castView in enum Finder cannot be applied to given types;
required: View,int,String,Class<T>
found: View,int,String
reason: cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Object declared in method <T>castView(View,int,String,Class<T>)
```

Can anybody tell me what am i missing here ?

Comment: Please consider cleaning your project and then rebuild

Comment: Thanks for comment i did that you suggested . But i have found solution . I was using two different versions in my gradle file . pls have a look a my answer. @Eenvincible

Comment: I am glad you figured it out; happy coding

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok It was minor mistake .

I was using different versions in gradle files .

```
 compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
 apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
```

now when i changed version its working properly. So some version conflict would be there.

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
  apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'
```

Comment: This answer saved me after I spent a good couple of hours going round in circles. Thanks.

Comment: I copied the compiler import from the changelog. That caused this issue. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I had done the same thing. your answer helped me

Comment: An annotation processor was included in the Gradle version 2.2, so there is no reason to provide an extra one. Check my updated answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43329827/2598453).

Comment: exactly my case (with the same versions). Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Just one more suggestions on this issue 
add in your gradle file. 
***apply plugin: 'android-apt'***

This save me as I faced similar kind of issue .
Error:(29, 0) Could not find method apt() for arguments [com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: Thanks for that! I would like to put one more thing. Do not forget to add classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8' in your build.gradle as well.