# Android Studio Warning: Using incompatible plugins for the annotation processing

Tags: android, android-studio, warnings

After update Android Studio to 2.3 version I have warning:

> Warning:Using incompatible plugins for the annotation processing:
>   android-apt. This may result in an unexpected behavior.

Any solutions? My app stopped working...

Comment: Android studio now has inbuilt annotation processing at compile time - you can remove the use of the `android-apt` and use `annotationProcessor` instead.  I don't know your particular usecase of `andorid-apt` but you should check the latest gradle setup for the dependency you're using it for.

Comment: So i should change
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
to
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.annotationProcessor'?

Comment: No @K.Kempski you don't have to apply any plugin now. Simply use annotationProcessor or provide in app gradle.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Your app level gradle dependencies should include (as per butterknife website instructions):

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

You can remove the line :

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

Annotation Processing became available in Android Gradle plugin (2.2 and later) so there is now no need to use the above plugin anymore if using this version of gradle or greater.

If you'd like to know how to turn annotation processing off and on and AS the setting is in :

**Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Annotation Processors**

Comment: Hey, i have the same problem. But I do not have :

apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

OR

annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'

written in my build gradle file.

I was using :

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'

now, after i have added the updated libraries and annotationProcessor, i still cant get my project to run and have the same error. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @legalimpurity In your comment this : `But I do not have : apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt' ` and this `i still cant get my project to run and have the same error` contradict what the error is in the OP question? If gradle is reporting `Warning:Using incompatible plugins for the annotation processing: android-apt.` then you have a conflict or outdated plugin. Or is this different to what you mean?

Comment: I also have the same issue as @legalimpurity is describing.

Comment: @tricknology see this: https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/issues/73/no-longer-compatible-with-gradle-at-v230 its not just about Butterknife (although this OP was) it is to do with android-apt no longer be supported

Comment: @tricknology : Thanks for sharing the link, I have gone through my build scripts and no where am i using android-apt, apt, androidTestApt, testApt ? any suggestions ?

Comment: @tricknology : I mean, I am still not able to remove that error.

Comment: @legalimpurity do you have any submodules that might be using it?  As a workaround just downgrade the gradle plugin.

Comment: @legalimpurity, K. Kempski's solution below worked for me - removing the annotation processor in butterknife (just commented out the line altogether). I'm not sure how reasonable it is for you though.

Answer (score 39):

In my project I use, among other things, Butter Knife and Immutables. After adding Immutables I got the following warning

> Warning:Using incompatible plugins for the annotation processing:
>   android-apt. This may result in an unexpected behavior.

and ButterKnife stopped working.

My configuration was as follows:

**build.gradle (Project: MyApplication)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}
```

**build.gradle (Module: app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

...

dependencies {

    ...

    // Butter Knife
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'

    // Immutables
    apt 'org.immutables:value:2.4.4'
    provided 'org.immutables:value:2.4.4'
    provided 'org.immutables:builder:2.4.4'
    provided 'org.immutables:gson:2.4.4'

}
```

After changing

```
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
```

to

```
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
```

warning disappeared and everything works as it should.

**UPDATE**

As Mark said, an annotation processor was included in the Gradle version 2.2 , so there is no reason to provide an extra one.

So:

1) Remove the class path for the apt from the **build.gradle (Project: MyApplication)**

```
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
```

2) Remove the plug in from the **build.gradle (Module: app)**

```
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
```

3) Change the dependencies from apt to the new annotationProcessor

```
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
annotationProcessor 'org.immutables:value:2.4.4'
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to @Milan's answer, if you used the hotchemi permissiondispatcher library in your app level gradle file then you should replace it as follows:

Replace

```
apt 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:2.4.0'
```

with

```
annotationProcessor 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:2.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

At Project Gradle `buildscript --> dependencies` block, remove the second `classpath` line :

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    // classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

And at app Gradle `dependencies` block, change these lines, use `api` and `annotationProcessor` :

```
api 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.19'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.19'
```

Also, remove this one:

```
//apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```