# ButterKnife and AnnotationProcessor

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, butterknife

Based on [ButterKnife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) lib, I upgrade to new version 8.5.1. I used

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
```

But it warns me in my Android Studio 2.3.  And ButterKnife doesn't work(cannot bind view).

> Warning:Using incompatible plugins for the annotation processing:
>   android-apt. This may result in an unexpected behavior.

I change  **annotationProcessor** to **apt** (I had plugin `apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'` in my gradle) and it works as old version without warning (I used apt for old version 8.4.0)

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
```

I think Android Studio 2.3 is incomatible with Annottaion processing. I searched and found to **enable Annotation Processors in Android Studio 2.2 but cannot find in Android Studio 2.3**

> Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Annotation
>   Processors

Anyone can explain this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Nope. I'm using the same thing in 2.3 no problem..

Comment: I don't know, Do you use `apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'`? @KiranBennyJoseph

Comment: Nope.......I don't use it

Comment: Hi. I had same problem as you. Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43329827/2598453).

Answer (score 6):

kindly

```
//apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'  <--remove this
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'  <-- add this


dependencies {
    //classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'  <-- remove this
    classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.5.1' <-- add this
}
```

then in app dependencies

//Butterknife

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
```

Comment: I will check it, thanks. But when we use `classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.5.1'` for parent gradle. We only need `apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'` for modules right. No need `compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'`?

Comment: so far as im concerned, `compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1' ` and `annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'` is needed..

Answer (score 3):

Simple and easy. Just add these lines to your build.gradle

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
```

Comment: Well I expect someone to tell me whats wrong while downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

An annotation processor was included in the Gradle version 2.2, so there is no reason to provide an extra one.

Check my updated answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43329827/2598453).