# Android Using incompatible plugins for the annotation processing

Tags: android

after more work on my project and install ro remove some libraries. i get this error as:

```
Warning:Using incompatible plugins for the annotation processing: 
android-apt. This may result in an unexpected behavior.
```

i search more sites about this problem but i can't resolve that

this is my application `build.gradle` content file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.pishguy.cafealachiqpro"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url "https://clojars.org/repo/" }
}

def dbflow_version = "4.0.0-beta5"
def sqlcipher_version = "3.5.4"

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'

    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'

    compile('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    compile 'com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android:+'
    compile 'com.facebook.rebound:rebound:0.3.8'
    compile 'com.tumblr:backboard:0.1.0'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    apt "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-processor:${dbflow_version}"
    // use kapt for kotlin apt
    compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-core:${dbflow_version}"
    compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow:${dbflow_version}"
    // sql-cipher database encryption (optional)
    compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-sqlcipher:${dbflow_version}"
    compile "net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:${sqlcipher_version}@aar"

    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
}
```

and this content is for project `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

what i get error: i get this result on `LogCat`

```
Warning:Using incompatible plugins for the annotation processing: android-apt. This may result in an unexpected behavior.
/Users/mahdi/Desktop/Home/Projects/Android/CafeAlachiqPro/app/src/main/java/ir/pishguy/cafealachiqpro/Ui/Register/Activity/View/ActivityRegister.java
Error:(48, 45) error: package ir.pishguy.cafealachiqpro.databinding does not exist
Error:(75, 13) error: cannot find symbol class ActivityRegisterBinding
/Users/mahdi/Desktop/Home/Projects/Android/CafeAlachiqPro/app/src/main/java/ir/pishguy/cafealachiqpro/Ui/Register/Robot/RobotMessagesAdapter.java
Error:(12, 45) error: package ir.pishguy.cafealachiqpro.databinding does not exist
Error:(13, 45) error: package ir.pishguy.cafealachiqpro.databinding does not exist
/Users/mahdi/Desktop/Home/Projects/Android/CafeAlachiqPro/app/src/main/java/ir/pishguy/cafealachiqpro/Ui/Register/Robot/RobotViewHolder.java
Error:(6, 45) error: package ir.pishguy.cafealachiqpro.databinding does not exist
Error:(13, 13) error: cannot find symbol class RobotDataBinding
Error:(15, 28) error: cannot find symbol class RobotDataBinding
/Users/mahdi/Desktop/Home/Projects/Android/CafeAlachiqPro/app/src/main/java/ir/pishguy/cafealachiqpro/Ui/Register/Robot/UserViewHolder.java
Error:(6, 45) error: package ir.pishguy.cafealachiqpro.databinding does not exist
Error:(13, 13) error: cannot find symbol class UserMessagesDataBinding
Error:(15, 27) error: cannot find symbol class UserMessagesDataBinding
```

all of binding classes are correct i checked them by click on each binded classes

Comment: An annotation processor was included in the Gradle version 2.2, so there is no reason to provide an extra one. Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43329827/2598453).

Answer (score 1):

Remove

`apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'`

or

`apply plugin: 'android-apt'`

and change `apt` dependencies to `annotationProcessor` like:

`apt 'com.contentful.vault:compiler:0.9.9'`

to

`annotationProcessor 'com.contentful.vault:compiler:0.9.9'`

Answer (score 0):

```
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

You're applying two different versions of the same plugin.  You should only use one of them.  Which one?  No clue, depends on why you added the second one to begin with.

Comment: using only one of them couldn't resolve my problem sir

Comment: It will fix the problem of using incompatible plugins.  If you have further issues beyond that, no clue.

Comment: could you help me on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43269050/6596724 no any body can help me

Answer (score 0):

An annotation processor was included in the Gradle version 2.2, so there is no reason to provide an extra one.

Check my updated answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43329827/2598453).