# Android update recyclerView items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i have simple problem on update `recyclerview` items by new data, i'm wondering which code work fine without using data binding, in my code adding new items trigger by click on button as `clickOnSendCommandToRobot` method, this method must add new item into `List` and my adapter can be know that to add new data and refresh `RecyclerView`, i dont get any error, but list size is `1` always

```
public class ActivityRegister extends BaseActivities {
    private RobotMessagesAdapter adapter;
    private List<RobotViewModel> model;
    private static final String TAG = "register";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_register);

        ActivityRegisterPresenter presenter = new ActivityRegisterPresenter(this);
        ActivityRegisterViewModel viewModel = new ActivityRegisterViewModel();
        binding.setViewModel(viewModel);
        binding.setPresenter(presenter);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            model = new ArrayList<>();
        } else {
            model = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("model");
        }
        adapter = new RobotMessagesAdapter(this, model);
        binding.registerRobot.setAdapter(adapter);

        ...
    }
    @Override
    public void clickOnSendCommandToRobot() {
        RobotViewModel temp = new RobotViewModel();
        temp.setMessage(Math.round(Math.random()) + "");
        temp.setMessageType(SV.RobotMessageType.SENT_BY_ROBOT.ordinal());
        model.add(temp);

        Log.e(TAG, model.size() + "");

        adapter.setData(model);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putParcelableArrayList("model", (ArrayList) model);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

adapter `setData` method:

```
public void setData(List<RobotViewModel> data) {
    Log.e("data size ", data.size() + "");
    list.clear();
    list.addAll(data);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

for each clicking on button and trigger `clickOnSendCommandToRobot` method. `model` variable clear and i don't have latest added items into that and adapter dont refresh list by new added item. 
Logcat:

```
04-08 08:29:45.342 21470-21470/com.sample.myapp E/register: 1
04-08 08:29:45.343 21470-21470/com.sample.myapp E/data size: 1
04-08 08:29:46.658 21470-21470/com.sample.myapp E/register: 1
04-08 08:29:46.658 21470-21470/com.sample.myapp E/data size: 1
04-08 08:29:47.462 21470-21470/com.sample.myapp E/register: 1
04-08 08:29:47.462 21470-21470/com.sample.myapp E/data size: 1
```

Comment: Remove list.clear() and than try.

rather than it I think their is no problem in code.

Comment: @KeyurThumar post updated, please review that, thanks

Comment: @MikeM. yes sir, i'm sure, this code work fine when i dont use data binding feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the model is a reference to the recycler view adapter itself, any changes made to the outside model object links back to adapter.So outside your adapter class where model is located just, call notifyDataSetChange there.so `adapter.setData(model);` remove and simply do `adapter.notifyDatasetChange();`

```
 @Override
    public void clickOnSendCommandToRobot() {
        RobotViewModel temp = new RobotViewModel();
        temp.setMessage(Math.round(Math.random()) + "");
        temp.setMessageType(SV.RobotMessageType.SENT_BY_ROBOT.ordinal());
        model.add(temp);

        Log.e(TAG, model.size() + "");

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();        }
```

Comment: removing  `list.clear();` cause of have duplicate items, i remove `notifyDataSetChanged` from adapter and move it into activity such as your code, `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` unfortunately problem dont resolve and  cause of clear `model` content on each trigger methos

Comment: what , did you remove call to set data

Comment: it seems problem resolved, but i have a question, where adapter can be know data changed? i use `adapter.setData(model);` to add items to adapter

Comment: what i normally do is before i changed any anything related to adapter, first call adapter.getItemCount() , then after change recall it, then compare if there is a difference then there you go. make sense?

Comment: could you help me on this topic? http://stackoverflow.com/q/43894042/6596724 Thanks in advance