# Android refreshing adapter work after rotation again device

Tags: android, mvvm

This code works fine when i add some data into 'List model' and restore saved data on rotation device, unfortunately after restore data and set that to `model` within `onRestoreInstanceState` method, after adding other data to that, **adapter** could not refresh with new added data, data source in adapter after can be updated, but adapter can;t know them , I'm using `MVVM` data model binding and search more time about this problem i can't resolve that.

Rhat have a simple tip which after rotation **again** device, my adapter can be refresh with all added data which adapter don't refresh with them.

```
public class ActivityRegister extends BaseActivities{
    private  List<RobotViewModel> model  = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putParcelable("model", Parcels.wrap(model));
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        model = Parcels.unwrap(outState.getParcelable("model"));

        adapter.setData(model);
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(model.size() - 1);
        binding.registerRobot.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);
    }
```

add to `model` method:

```
    @Override
    public void clickOnSendCommandToRobot() {
        RobotViewModel temp = new RobotViewModel();

temp.setMessage("message");

        temp.setCommand(true);

        model.add(temp);

        adapter.notifyItemInserted(model.size() - 1);
        binding.registerRobot.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);
    }
```

My Adapter Class:

```
public class RobotMessagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private List<RobotViewModel> list;
    private LayoutInflater       inflater;

    public RobotMessagesAdapter(List<RobotViewModel> robotViewModels) {
        this.list = robotViewModels;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (inflater == null) {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        }
        if (viewType == SV.RobotMessageType.SENT_BY_USER.ordinal()) {
            return new UserViewHolder(UserMessagesDataBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false));
        } else {
            return new RobotViewHolder(RobotDataBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case 0:
                ((UserViewHolder) holder).bind(list.get(position));
                break;
            case 1:
                ((RobotViewHolder) holder).bind(list.get(position));
                break;
        }
    }

    ...

    public void setData(List<RobotViewModel> data) {
        Log.e("data size ", data.size() + "");
        list.clear();
        list.addAll(data);
    }
}
```

I'm wondering why this code work fine:

```
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        model = Parcels.unwrap(outState.getParcelable("model"));

        adapter.setData(model);
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(model.size() - 1);
        binding.registerRobot.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);

        RobotViewModel temp = new RobotViewModel();

temp.setMessage("message");

        temp.setCommand(true);

        model.add(temp);

        adapter.notifyItemInserted(model.size() - 1);
        binding.registerRobot.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);
    }
```

without any problem and after move this lines:

```
        RobotViewModel temp = new RobotViewModel();

temp.setMessage("message");

        temp.setCommand(true);

        model.add(temp);

        adapter.notifyItemInserted(model.size() - 1);
        binding.registerRobot.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);
```

to other method that doesn't work :|

My presenter:

```
public class ActivityRegisterPresenter {
    private ActivityRegisterContract view;

    public ActivityRegisterPresenter(ActivityRegisterContract mView) {
        view = mView;
    }

    ...
}
```

and my ViewModel:

```
public class ActivityRegisterViewModel extends BaseObservable {
    private String readContactPermission;
    private String getMessages;

    public ActivityRegisterViewModel() {
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getReadContactPermission() {
        return readContactPermission;
    }

    public void setReadContactPermission(String readContactPermission) {
        this.readContactPermission = readContactPermission;
        notifyChange();
    }

    public String getGetMessages() {
        return getMessages;
    }

    public void setGetMessages(String getMessages) {
        this.getMessages = getMessages;
    }
}
```

[SOURCE CODE IS HERE](https://ufile.io/g351w)

problems are in `clickOnRegisterMobileNumber` and `clickOnSendCommandToRobot` methods

Comment: so rotation is the problem?

Comment: @Remario after change device rotation and adding more item with `clickOnSendCommandToRobot` method. i dont see them on adapter but after rotate again device i see them on the adapter

Comment: @Remario my post updated

Comment: Alright, give me some time, soon post an answer!

Comment: @Remario Thanks a lot, would you like to get source with me?

Comment: thats weird , that logic should work though

Comment: the binding class, show it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143895/discussion-between-tux-world-and-remario).

Comment: which part exactly does not work , after you move it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My problem resolved,

after adding this below line into manifest for specific activity where you setAdapter

```
android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|screenLayout"
```

But it will return best view if you design Both Portrait and Landscape layout or running app only in one mode of these both.

Answer (score 1):

```
The main reason is that, because you called set-data and that method did not immediately notify that the data set was changed, therefore it was not ware.

      public void setData(List<RobotViewModel> data) {
            Log.e("data size ", data.size() + "");
            list.clear();
            list.addAll(data);
        }
```

> ```
>      public void setData(List<RobotViewModel> data) {
>             Log.e("data size ", data.size() + "");
> ```

```
            list.clear();
            notifyDataSetChanged(); //here,to signal change occurred.
            list.addAll(data);
            notifyDataSetChanged(); //here,to signal change occurred.

        }

should probably get into the habit of notifying changes on the spot.
```

The main problem is this, you never notified the changes you made, you cleared it , but you never told it, you know, bu the adapter does not know, also you inserted fresh data with `addAll` but you still did not notify it.

Comment: another reason is that you used  list.addAll(data);, but you never cleaned nor deleted the previous model data. i think you meant to add a single entry to already existing entries!

Comment: problem is notify adapter to renew with new saved data into `model` after rotation device `setData` for fine and refresh my adapter, but after add more data to `model` by for example click on button can not notify my adapter to renew with new data, simply couldn't refresh, using `setData` on click method cause of clear all my data on adapter

Comment: unfortunately problem don't resole sir, you can test this project https://ufile.io/g351w  problems are in `clickOnRegisterMobileNumber` method and `clickOnSendCommandToRobot`

Comment: @Remario: `notifyDataSetChanged()` should be called after the data editing, so after `list.addAll(data)`. Am I wrong?

Comment: yea that is right, this is based on internal implementation of state. when you put data into it, it caches and remember that data state, if something happens and you do not notify it of changes, it wont know that the state as changed.

Comment: anytime any state as changed(deleted|modified|inserted) immediately notify the adapter.

Comment: whats your current status?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works just fine with few updates.
When you perform this action

```
 model.add(temp);
 adapter.notifyItemInserted(model.size() - 1);
```

You are assuming the persistence of the link between the object model and the adapter datasource.
This assumption is wrong, in fact if you just replace the code above with

```
 model.add(temp);
 adapter.setData(model);
 adapter.notifyItemInserted(model.size() - 1);
```

it works fine.
I hope it helped.